# How to find an inverse of the following function?

Tags: inverse

$$f(x)=x^3+1$$
To find inverse, from what I've learned we change the y to x

$$x=y^3+1$$
solve for y
$$x-1=y^3$$

Should I cube  root the x-1 for this? if i did that I still would not get the answer that would match the answer choice given to me

What should i do after this?

Comment: yes your steps are well fixed

Comment: @MATH ASKER What are your answer choices?

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=x^3+1$$$$y=x^3+1$$$$y-1=x^3$$$$x=(y-1)^{\frac13}$$$$f^{-1}(x)=(x-1)^{\frac13}$$

Answer (score 2):

$(x-1)^{1/3}$ or $(x-1)^{1/3} \omega$ or $(x-1)^{1/3} \omega^2$, where $\omega = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

The function is invertible over reals - and the inverse is $(x-1)^{1/3}$, however, the function is not invertible in the complex domain since there is no unique inverse.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^3+1$

$x^3+1=y$

$x=\sqrt[3]{y-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Inverting the graph of $f$ (red curve) means mirroring at the line $\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}\id(x)=x$ (blue line).

[image: f and inverse]

It can often happen that the resulting graph is not the graph of a function, because it turns multiple valued at some $x$-coordinates. 
But here (green curve) everything is fine.

This shows up in your correct algebraic invertation, where the last step would be
$$
y = \sqrt[3]{x - 1} = (x - 1)^{1/3}
$$